# Is there a public rubygems.org mirror?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

Is there a working public mirror for http://rubygems.org? It's not working now for me, http://isup.me/rubygems.org says that it doesn't work too.

Comment: Working just fine for me.

Comment: Works for me too, but strangely, this site also shows it as down: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rubygems.org

Comment: @Dogbert, it is another url for the site from my question. It looks strange, but amazon.com also aren't working for me now (AFAIK rubygems.org is hosted on amazon aws). Is there any idea why?

Comment: +1 good question. in this specific case `isup.me` does not show the correct situation, but what, if rubygems.org is really down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RedHat OpenShift provides own RubyGems mirror: http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/

Comment: Doesn't work for me now. I get a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Yes, you'll get 403 error if you try to open the URL in browser. But if you create a Gemfile with first line `source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'` it will work like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much. rubygems was not working for me due to some DNS issues but this mirror worked like a breeze

Comment: That URL doesn't seem to work anymore, but this one does: `http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/`

Comment: Life saver.  DNSIMPLE DDOS is destroying rubygems.

Comment: I've just set one up too in case its helpful to anyone. https://rubygems.cae.me.uk